# overlapping div tag in css

Tags: css, overlay

I was wondering if anyone can assist me on obtaining a look like : http://www.groupon.com/los-angeles/ where they have that price tag overlapping the border. How do I accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to absolute position one on the other.

**See Demo Here:** http://jsfiddle.net/Zsg8c/